# Calling function that has parameter inside lambda in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, higher-order-functions

I have a Kotlin function `fun myFun(book:Book){...}`. How do I pass `myFun` to a function that accepts a lambda?

fun acceptor(task: (book:Book) -> Unit){
     var someBook = ...
     ...
     task(someBook)
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass {

    fun myFun(book:Book) {
        ...
    }

    fun otherThatCallsAccept() {
        /* other stuff */
        acceptor(::myFun)
    }
}
```

Edit: you can't call `acceptor` without a parameter, but you can define a default empty lambda,

```
fun acceptor(task: (book:Book) -> Unit = {}) {
    /* body here */
}
```

Comment: is there a way to call `acceptor` without a parameter?

Comment: btw thanks for understanding the question. Other people I ask keep thinking I am talking about passing a function as a parameter -- even Google searches found nothing.